# How to show maps side by side?

Tags: javascript, dictionary, flask, leaflet, layer

I have a flask application where i am using the leaflet map with the values offered by https://aqicn.org/faq/2015-09-18/map-web-service-real-time-air-quality-tile-api/ to display pm2.5, air quality index and other values in a side by side map. So far, I have managed to display all values on layers, and i don't know how to make the map display all values at the same time, like the one in the picture:
[image]

So far I have this:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
{% extends "menu.html" %}
<head>

    <title>{% block title %}Map{% endblock %}</title>

    <meta charset="utf-8"/>

    {% block dependencies %}
        <style>
            html {
                height: 100%
            }

            body {
                height: 100%;
                margin: 0;
            }


            #map {
                height: 800px;

            }


        </style>
    {% endblock %}

</head>
<body>
{% block content %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.5/leaflet.css"/>
    <script src="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.5/leaflet.js"></script>
    <div id='map' class="a"></div>

    <script>
        var mbUrl_aqi = 'https://tiles.aqicn.org/tiles/usepa-' + 'aqi' + '/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?token=?';
        var mbUrl_pm25 = 'https://tiles.aqicn.org/tiles/usepa-' + 'pm25' + '/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?token=?';
        var mbUrl_pm10 = 'https://tiles.aqicn.org/tiles/usepa-' + 'pm10' + '/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?token=?';
        var mbUrl_o3 = 'https://tiles.aqicn.org/tiles/usepa-' + 'o3' + '/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?token=?';
        var mbUrl_no2 = 'https://tiles.aqicn.org/tiles/usepa-' + 'no2' + '/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?token=?';
        var mbUrl_so2 = 'https://tiles.aqicn.org/tiles/usepa-' + 'so2' + '/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?token=?';
        var mbUrl_co = 'https://tiles.aqicn.org/tiles/usepa-' + 'co' + '/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?token=?';
        var aqi = L.tileLayer(mbUrl_aqi);
        var pm25 = L.tileLayer(mbUrl_pm25);
        var pm10 = L.tileLayer(mbUrl_pm10);
        var o3 = L.tileLayer(mbUrl_o3);
        var no2 = L.tileLayer(mbUrl_no2);
        var so2 = L.tileLayer(mbUrl_so2);
        var co = L.tileLayer(mbUrl_co);
        var map = L.map('map', {
            center: [45.657974, 25.601198],
            zoom: 11,
            layers: [aqi]
        });

        var baseLayers = {
            "aqi": aqi,
            "pm25": pm25,
            "pm10": pm10,
            "no2": no2,
            "so2": so2,
            "co": co,
            "o3": o3
        };

        {#    resize #}
        document.getElementById("map").style.resize = "both";
        var WAQI_ATTR = '&copy;  <a  href="http://waqi.info">waqi.info</a>';

        var credits_url = 'http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png';
        var credits_attrib = '&copy;  <a  href="http://openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>';
        var osmLayer = L.tileLayer(credits_url, {attribution: [credits_attrib, WAQI_ATTR]});
        map.addLayer(osmLayer);
        L.control.layers(baseLayers).addTo(map);

    </script>
{% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

The code displays the following:
How to show all maps side by side?

[image]

Comment: It's not very clear: do you want 6 maps next to one another or all the 6 values on the same map?

Comment: @djcaesar9114 ideally, i would like each value on a separate map, so 6 maps in total. I would like that when i move the first map(let's say there are pm2.5 values on that one), all other 5 would move to the cities i move the first map to. For example, if i show London on the first map, the other 5 should show London too, but showing the different values(pm10, air quality index and so on). How can I reach this?

Comment: Please give a fiddle of working code, it will be easier than just having a short javascript code.

Comment: @djcaesar9114 I have updated the question with working code :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works. You can play with CSS or the DOM to change the display of the maps, but there you have something working (also, you can improve the code because there is a repetition and a repetition is never good).

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
  var layerTypes = ['aqi', 'pm25', 'pm10', 'o3', 'no2', 'so2', 'co']
  var maps = []
  layerTypes.forEach(function(layer){
    var t = document.createElement('div');
    t.setAttribute("id", "map_"+layer);
    t.setAttribute("class", "map");
    document.getElementById("maps").appendChild(t);
    var m = L.tileLayer('https://tiles.aqicn.org/tiles/usepa-' + layer + '/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?token=?');
    var map = L.map('map_'+layer, {
      center: [45.657974, 25.601198],
      zoom: 11,
      layers: [m]
    });

    map.on("zoomend", function (e) {
      var zoom = map.getZoom();
      var center = map.getCenter();
      maps.forEach(function(everyMap){
        everyMap.setView(center, zoom);
      })
    });
    map.on("moveend", function (e) {
      var zoom = map.getZoom();
      var center = map.getCenter();
      maps.forEach(function(everyMap){
        everyMap.setView(center, zoom);
      })
    });

    var baseLayers = {};
    baseLayers[layer] = m,
    document.getElementById("map_"+layer).style.resize = "both";
    var WAQI_ATTR = '&copy;  <a  href="http://waqi.info">waqi.info</a>';

    var credits_url = 'http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png';
    var credits_attrib = '&copy;  <a  href="http://openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>';
    var osmLayer = L.tileLayer(credits_url, {attribution: [credits_attrib, WAQI_ATTR]});
    map.addLayer(osmLayer);
    L.control.layers(baseLayers).addTo(map);
    maps.push(map)
  });

});
```

```css
    html {
        height: 100%
    }

    body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
    }


    .map {
        height: 200px;
 width: 200px;

    }
```

```html
<link href="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.5/leaflet.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.5/leaflet.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="maps"></div>
```

Comment: That is great! Thank you so much!